# Finding files from list and copying them into new directory

Tags: macos, terminal, find

I want to find files via the command line terminal for OS X and then copy the files that were found to a new directory. The filenames of the files I want to find are in a listexample.txt file and there are about 5000 file names in there.

The file listexample.txt looks like this:

```
1111 00001 55553.bmp
1113 11312 24125.bmp
…
```

I tried around with thing like this:

```
find /directory -type f "`cat listexample.txt`" -exec cp {} …
```

but can't get it to run.

I have now this, but it doesn't work:

```
cat listexample.txt | while read line; do grep "$line" listexample.txt -exec find /directorya "$line" -exec cp {} /directoryb \; done
```

The idea is to read the lines of list example.txt, then take the line with grep, find the file in directory a and then copy the found file over to a new directory b. I think because of the nature of my file names, see above, there is a problem with spaces in the name as well.

I also started this approach to see what is going on, but didn't get far.

```
for line in `cat listexample.txt`; do grep $line -exec echo "Processing $line"; done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the solution for a find and copy script (copy.sh) in case somebody has a similar problem:

First, give rights to the script with: `chmod +x fcopy.sh`
Then run it with: `./fcopy.sh listexample.txt`

Script content:

```
#!/bin/bash
target="/directory with images"

while read line
do
    name=$line
    echo "Text read from file - $name"
    find "${target}" -name "$name" -exec cp {} /found_files \;    

done < $1
```

Cheers